# Sum Of Small Divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here, $a(n):=\sum\limits_{d\mid n\\d\leq\sqrt{n}} d$ is the sum of those divisors of $n$ that do not exceed $\sqrt{n}$. In the Douglas E. Iannucci paper "Sums of the Small Divisors of a Natural Number" it is mentioned that $$\delta>\frac{1}{2}\implies L(\delta):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(n)}{n^{\delta}}=0$$ with a reference made to Apostol which is still unclear. Is there an elementary proof for this conditional statement ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just follows from the inequality
$$
a(n) =\sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d\le \sqrt n}} d \le \sum_{\substack{d\mid n \\ d\le \sqrt n}} \sqrt n \le \tau(n)\sqrt n,
$$
where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, together with the classical inequality $\tau(n) \ll_\varepsilon n^\varepsilon$ for every $\varepsilon>0$.